# Is there an indepth architectural description of the Asp.NET MVC 2 framework?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

Not so much a "How to" of how to use the framework, but a good description of how the framework itself is put together?

web site? book?

or just the source code? :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I was learning version 1, I found [this article](http://lostintangent.com/2008/07/03/aspnet-mvc-controlleractioninvoker-part-1/) (and the included diagram) very helpful in establishing a high-level picture. Aside from that, I read [Scott Guthrie's articles](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/tags/MVC/default.aspx), and tidbits from various bloggers. And I almost always had an instance of VS running with the official source code loaded in it. Haven't played with version 2 yet, but as far as I can tell, the fundamental architecture is very much the same.

Comment: not really interested in that kind of answer, am well versed in OO and well aware of various architectural patterns and design principles. Am happy to mine the source code, but just looking to see if anyone else has something already.

I'd be interested in knowing which books talk about the design and structure of the framework itself

Comment: nice! first article is much closer to what I'm interested in!

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you'll find anything other than a description of how Controllers, Views and Models are related to each other, if you search for something broad like that. Sure you'll run into some blog posts which describe some under-the-hood stuff but you'll have to put the pieces together yourself.

What I suggest is this ; Don't try to discover everything at once. But try to learn one thing at a time, as reading the source code. For example, what's responsible for invoking the actions and how does it do it, etc?

But if you find resources about how everything is put together, do share :)

Answer (score 1):

Other resources (either light on details and/or very early version 1) I have found are :-

http://www.red-gate.com/products/ants_performance_profiler/be_ahead_of_the_game_poster1.htm

http://blog.stevensanderson.com/2007/11/20/aspnet-mvc-pipeline-lifecycle/